# In Xcode how do I get files to open in the same window

Tags: xcode

I'm running XCode 3.2, and when I double click on a file in Groups and Files it always opens in a new window.  What I'd like is for it to appear in the main Xcode editor.  I've tried changes the preferences in the Xcode preference panel without any success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a single click rather than double click.  In the All In One layout (Preferences, General) the editor is a pane in the Xcode window and files will appear there when you merely select them from the list.  A double click gives you the file in a separate window.

Comment: I closed my project, set my preference to the All In One layout, and still no dice.  When I single click a file it appears in the top File Detail pane, but not in the editor.

Comment: I'd been tearing my hair out over this one too; then I realized I never restart xcode.  That sorted it out...

Answer (score 1):

If you using Xcode as a new project there should be a button on the right side of the editor toolbar that toggles between Grouped and Ungrouped. When you click that, and open a new file, it will use the same editor window instead of creating a new window for each file.

If you not using Xcode as a new project, and just the editor, trying single clicking.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted X-Code and things are working perfectly now.  Aargh!